# Finding derivative given values of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am given this function to calculate the derivatitve.

> $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{x}$ at $x=5$

They also gave me a table of values:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
x&1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
f(x) & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 3\\
f'(x) & 3 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 4\\
g(x) & 4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
g'(x) & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 5
\end{array}$$

I have tried using the `quotient rule` with no luck. I have also tried using the `product rule` on $f(x)g(x)$ then applying the `quotient rule` afterwords, but no luck. Can anyone show me how to tackle this bad boy?

**Quotient rule answer:**
$$h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)g'(x)(x)-1f(x)g(x)}{x^2}=\frac{97}{25}$$
**Product rule answer:**
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)=19$$
so we have,
$$\frac{19}{x}$$
Then,
$$\frac{d}{dx}19x^{-1}=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)=19/x^2=\frac{19}{25}$$

Comment: What do you get after applying quotient rule/product rule?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt ill update rn with my answers.

Comment: A combination of product rules and quotient rules is exactly what you need.

Comment: @DougM I included my work, can you show what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the quotient rule.  Indeed, it should be

$$\frac d{dx}\frac{fg}x=\frac{(fg)'x-(fg)x'}{x^2}$$

Where

$$x'=1$$

$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$

And the rest is just plugging in numbers.

Comment: Thank You! I did not see the relationship $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ but that totally makes sense:)

Comment: what would be the actual answer? I see your formula but when I try to work it out I get $\frac{16}{5}$ which is wrong.:(

Comment: @NickPavini I'll have to work it myself in about an hour.  Riding the bus until then ;-/

Comment: OK I will keep trying haha

Comment: @NickPavini Ok, I'm back.  Working it out, I get $(fg)'=19$ and $$\left(\frac{fg}x\right)'=\frac{(19)(5)-(3)(1)}{5^2}=\frac{92}{25}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {d}{dx} \frac {f(x)g(x)}{x} =  \frac {x\frac {d}{dx}(f(x)g(x)) - f(x)g(x)}{x^2}$  (quotient rule)

$\frac {d}{dx}(f(x)g(x)) = f'(x) g(x) + g'(x) f(x)$ (product rule)

$\frac {d}{dx} \frac {f(x)g(x)}{x} =  \frac {xf'(x)g(x) + xf(x)g'(x) - f(x)g(x)}{x^2}$

Comment: You might want to check the "reviewing your work".  (notice $x=5\ne1$)